# Make Description tab by default active on product pages in magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, tabs

On product pages, by default specification tab is active. How can i make the first tab i.e Description tab active by default.
See https://5iallk0uwem1coeq.mojostratus.io/fabrics/zorb/zorb-original/zorb-silver.html page for reference
See https://prnt.sc/vbkov0

Comment: Please add file from where that tabs come from in code.

Comment: vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details.phtml

Comment: @Nafsss, You can simply use jQuery

Comment: I tried, but it did not work perfectly

Comment: jQuery('.product.data.items .data.item.title').removeClass('active');
jQuery('#tab-label-additional').addClass('active');

jQuery('.product.data.items .data.item.content').css('display','none'); 
jQuery('#additional').css('display','block');

Comment: try above in console

Comment: @Pawan This Makes specification tab active. I want description tab active

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115748/discussion-between-pawan-and-nafsss).

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal You have added some code. Can u please share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add this to your phtml file.

```
<script>
  require(
      [
          'jquery',
      ],
      function($) {
        $("a#tab-label-description-title").trigger('click');
      }
  );
</script>
```

Comment: Did not work......

Comment: @Nafsss use setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000); this function

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show description tab active on product pages,change code line in catalog_product_view.xml file

Here by default, "Details" tab is active, if you want to active "More Information" by default then,just change sort_order of "Details" tab to 20 from 10 and "More Information" tab to 10 from 20.Similarly by changing sort_order you can achieve your requirement.

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Details" name="product.info.details" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media">
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" as="description" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
<arguments>
<argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
<argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
<argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
<argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
<argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
<argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">20</argument>
</arguments>
 </block>
 <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
<arguments>
<argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
<argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">10</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
</block>
```